# How Do I Set Another Program as JPG Default in Windows 11

Tags: file-association, windows-11, default-settings

My computer was recently upgraded to Windows 11 and my default program for JPEG (.jpg, .jpeg) was changed from my preferred program of JPEGView to Photos (Windows default app). Photos takes a while to open and JPEGView opens much more quickly. I would like to change it back to JPEGView. However, there are no options in the "Default apps" settings page for JPEG images and file types.

If I scroll all the way to the bottom to change it for the specific .jpg file type, it does not exist.

[image: "jpg" does not work]

[image: ".jpg" does not work]

[image: "*.jpg" does not work]

If I go through all of the apps, including "Photos," that might be the default, JPEG is not an option.

[image: JPEGView Defaults]

[image: Photos Defaults]

[image: IrfanView Defaults]

[image: Paint.NET Defaults]

**Is there another settings page that would allow me to change this default? If Microsoft "hid" this, or if this is a bug, is there a registry setting that I could modify to change this?**

Some details about this computer: I am the administrator, it is not connected to an Active Directory domain, it is running as a VM that I remotely connect through either a) Spice, or b) Remote Desktop

**EDIT**

Selecting "Open With" does not provide an option to set the default. If I choose another app, it opens with that app, but only once. It does not set the default.

[image: The "Open With" menu]

[image: The "Open With" "Choose Another App" dialog]

**EDIT 2**

Digging around, I've discovered that this applies to PNG files as well. With other file types, such as TIFF and WEBP, there are options for setting the default within the Windows Properties dialog, Open With, and Default Apps. With PNG and JPEG, the button for "Change Default" does not exist in the Windows Properties dialog. It seems like these file types are "locked down" and are allowed to be changed. **The question is, "is this a bug or a feature?"**

**EDIT 3**

I just spoke with a co-worker who also upgraded his Windows 10 VM to Windows 11 and he does *not* have this problem. He is able to set the defaults for JPEG and PNG files.

Comment: Navigate to the file you wish to open. Right click and select Open With.  Can you open with your App?  If so you may, in that selection, set it to default App.

Comment: There is no option to set default in the Open With Dialog. I will get screen shots and add it to my post.

Comment: It is possible Windows 11 will not all that App as a default App.

Comment: That's not a good conjecture. First, JPEGView is the default for PNG files. So, I know the app is allowed. Second, it doesn't allow me to set ANY app because there are no options for the JPEG file type anywhere in the settings.

Comment: “Is there another settings page that would allow me to change this default?” - No; You can probably solve this problem by creating a key for those two file extensions.  You can do that by finding one of the file extensions that do exist in your registry, exporting it, then edit and import. I suggest using .tif as the template.

Comment: @Ramhound By "creating a key," I think you mean registry keys. .jpeg and .jpg already exist in the registry, so I don't think I need to create them. I'm assuming you believe this to be a bug or intentional, correct?

Comment: In the context of the registry, yes, I was indeed talking about registry keys. What you describe is NOT a bug.

Comment: @Ramhound I came to the opposite conclusion. I think it is a bug in the Photos appx package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally decided to search Google in a Guest profile and I added `-"how to"` to my search and was able to find some answers. It looks like there may be a bug in the Microsoft Photos app that causes this issue.

1. Apps and Features->Photos->"Advanced Options"->Reset (not Repair)

[image: Apps and Features Advanced Options]
[image: Reset]

2. Alternatively, open PowerShell as Administrator, run the following command: `Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Windows.Photos -AllUsers | Reset-AppxPackage`

I chose the PowerShell option and I am now able to change the defaults for JPEG and PNG files.

Here are some links for reference:

[Widows 11 setting default program for jpg files is not working](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/widows-11-setting-default-program-for-jpg-files-is/f70ec1d9-3c63-4b80-9c80-fd91e19685f8)

[Can't Change Default Apps Windows 11 (OS Build 22000.120)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/cant-change-default-apps-windows-11-os-build/17b96a09-86f0-4362-a3aa-da6eb765fc5b)

Comment: Worked for me too. Used the interface method. Only note, I didn't have the "Apps and feature" menu in Settings. To find the "Reset" button I had to search for Microsoft Photos in "Installed apps", click the three dots on the right and then "Advanced options"

Comment: I installed the Photos app (uninstalled it weeks ago), then run the PowerShell command above to reset the Photos app. Afterwards I was able to right-click a JPG file, select "Open With", and then there was (finally!) the "Always" button next to the "Just once" button.

Comment: Saved my day! Thanks. How could one figure this out by themselves...

Comment: Same issue as @il_mix but this worked otherwise!

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used PowerShell command mentioned by @mawsco, BUT first I needed to install Microsoft Photos app from the store.
While it wasn't installed the reset command would not work, and trying to use Choose another app from context menu would give me a slightly different (newer?) UI showing only "Just once" button. After I installed the Photos app, opened it, made sure it opens JPEGs, I ran the PowerShell command and then I tried context menu Choose another app option. This time there was an "Always" button available.

Just so many hoops to jump through in Windows 11 as if Microsoft wanted that people who worked with this software since Win 3.11 felt lost again...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1161807)

Answer (score 0):

Photos uninstallation:

Run Powershell as administrator
Paste and extract this code:

```
get-appxpackage *photos* | remove-appxpackage
```

---

Photos Reinstallation:

Run Powershell as administrator
Paste and extract this code:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers| Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

Comment: If reinstallation via PowerShell fails with a bunch of error messages, go to Microsoft Store, search for "Microsoft Photos" there and install it via the app store, then run reset as suggested above, then uninstall this idiotic software.